# Correlation between the proportion derived from the data of different size

Tags: r, correlation

I want to obtain a correlation between the accuracy of two linguistic features by language learners. The learners wrote a number of essays, and the number of correct and incorrect use of the article and the plural marker was tallied in each essay. The data for a learner look like the following, though the number of essays varies across learners.

```
Essay   ArticleCorrect   ArticleIncorrect   PluralCorrect   PluralIncorrect
  1          7                0                  2               1
  2          4                1                  0               2
  3          6                2                  3               1
  4          7                0                  2               1
  5          8                2                  1               3
 ...        ...              ...                ...             ...
 10          4                1                  2               0
```

What I would like to know is whether the performance of the learner on the article use is correlated with his/her performance on the plural marker (e.g., whether the accuracy of the plural marker tends to be high when the accuracy of the article is high).

Straightforwardly applying the Pearson correlation on the accuracy (i.e., $\frac{correct}{correct + incorrect}$ ) is not adequate as the number of attempts varies across essays as well as across the linguistic features. Weighted correlation, I believe, only allows weighting by essays but not by linguistic features.

Is there a way (preferably in R) to do the above? Any help is appreciated.